# Search and compare in values in an only table in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm

I write scripts for an results management of students in a school. I've a table with two dimensions.

```
$tabMoyenne[] = array($moduleId, $moyenneFinale);
```

In this table, there are several same moduleId and I can't calculate the sum of moyenneFinale per moduleId. I tried with loop and conditions if but it doesn't work and I haven't another idea.

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: I dont see what the question you are asking is.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use foreach and do something like below example.

```
$tabMoyenne[] = array('1', 100);
$tabMoyenne[] = array('1', 100);
$tabMoyenne[] = array('1', 100);
$tabMoyenne[] = array('2', 100);
$tabMoyenne[] = array('3', 300);


$sumMoyenneFinale = array();

foreach ($tabMoyenne as $value){
   $sumMoyenneFinale[$value[0]] +=  $value[1];
}

print_r($sumMoyenneFinale);
```